# Changing default state of accordion collapse panel with screen size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `accordion`

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">FAQ</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">       
              ...          
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I want the `accordion` default to be expanded on a desktop browser but collapsed on a mobile browser. I've tried changing `<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">` to `<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse var">` and having the following in my `.css`:

```
@media(max-width:767px) {
    .collapse.var{
        display:none;
    }
    .collapse.in.var{
        display:block;
    }
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .collapse.var{
        display:block;
    }
    .collapse.in.var{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

But the desktop version is bugged and the content is displayed even when the panel is gone. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Where is the `var` being using here?

Comment: @ManojKumar I changed `<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">` to `<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse var">`

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how to play with those `.collapse` class in **CSS** without breaking everything, but one solution to your request in **jQuery** would be:

```
$(window).on("load resize",function(e){
  if(window.innerwidth > 767){
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('show');
    $('.panel > a').removeClass('collapsed');
  } else {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $('.panel > a').addClass('collapsed');
  }
});
```

Hope this might help.